# Pac4j OIDC logout does not allow Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, openid-connect, pac4j

Hi I am using Pac4j to do login logout. It has this class called `OidcLogoutActionBuilder`, where inside it checks specifically if the request is an Ajax request (e.g. from SPA), it will reply with 403. I wonder why is it?

Would it be just some functional limitation (e.g. client does not do redirect from Ajax response) or is there some security concern?